# Is it good design to use factory pattern for creating Services?

Tags: design-patterns

I have read about Factory Pattern where it is used to create Objects on the fly based on some conditions. However, is it a norm to create Service classes based on those conditions.

```
class ServiceFactory { 

    DummService1 A;
    DummService2 B;
    DummService3 C;

    Service getService(String condition) {

      switch condition:
          case A:
             return new A()
          case B:
             return new B()
          case C:
             return new C()
    }
}

class DummyService1 implements Service{}
class DummyService2 implements Service{}
class DummyService3 implements Service{}
```

Above is an example. Also, I am trying to do this in Spring, so these service classes are Autowired (did not want to complicate the above example with Spring Specific syntax).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is it a norm to create Service classes based on those conditions.

It is one way of creating services. Another might be to use an SPI and the [`ServiceLoader`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ServiceLoader.html). But then you might introduce a method in the service itself to find out if it is suitable. E.g.

```
public Service {
    public boolean isSuitable(String condition);

    // ... Service methods
}
```

you might then lookup the correct service in this way

```
Service suitableService = null;

for(Service serviceCandidate : ServiceLoader.load(Service.class)){
   if(serviceCandidate.isSuitable(condition)){
        suitableService = serviceCandidate;
        break;
   }
}
```

In Java 8 you might replace the switch with a map of method references:

```
private Map<String, Supplier<Service>> services = new HashMap<>();

public ServiceFactory() {
    services.put("A", A::new);
    services.put("B", B::new);
    services.put("C", C::new);
}

Service getService(String condition) {
    Supplier<Service> supplier = services.get(condition);
    if(supplier != null) {
        return supplier.get();
    }
    return null;
}
```

> Also, I am trying to do this in Spring, so these service classes are Autowired

When you do this in spring you usually use [`@Qualifier`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#beans-scanning-qualifiers) instead of condition.

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("A")
private Service service;
```